# Associating current_user id to imported contacts list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to import CSV and Excel files into a rails 4 project (with validation) using the Roo gem, based on http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel.

The data gets imported to database and I can access them from the console. Here's the model method:

```
class ContactImport

  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :file, :user_id

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each { |name, value| send("#{name}=", value) }
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def save
    if imported_contacts.map(&:valid?).all?
      imported_contacts.each(&:save!)
      true
    else
      imported_contacts.each_with_index do |contact, index|
        contact.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          errors.add :base, "Row #{index+2}: #{message}"
        end
      end
      false
    end
  end

  def imported_contacts
    @imported_contacts ||= load_imported_contacts
  end

  def load_imported_contacts
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).map do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      contact = Contact.find_by_id(row["id"]) || Contact.new
      contact.attributes = row.to_hash.slice('first_name', 'last_name', 'mobile', 'email', 'info')
      contact.user_id = user_id
      contact
    end
  end

  def open_spreadsheet
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end
end
```

The controller looks like:

```
class ContactImportsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def new

    @contact_import = ContactImport.new
  end

  def create
    params[:contact_import].merge({user_id: current_user.id})
    @contact_import = ContactImport.new(contact_params)
    if @contact_import.save
      redirect_to contacts_path, notice: "Imported contacts successfully."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact_import).permit(:file, :user_id)
  end
end
```

I'm not sure how to add the current_user id to each contact. Would appreciate any solutions.

Comment: do your contact model has user_id field?

Comment: @Rubyrider yes, it does. I use that in the show page to filter out contacts that belong to each user.

Comment: So User has many contacts right? or many to many association? Based on these infos I can give you the right direction.

Comment: @Rubyrider the user has_many :contacts and the contact belongs_to :user. That's their relationship. There is no many to many association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, based on your given information you can do the following to add the current_user_id to your contact.

In your ContactImportController

```
   .........

  def create
    @contact_import = ContactImport.new(contact_params)
    @contact_import.user_id = current_user.id
    if @contact_import.save
      redirect_to contacts_path, notice: "Imported contacts successfully."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact_import).permit(:file)
  end

  .........
```

In your contact_import.rb file

```
 def load_imported_contacts
   spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet
   header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).map do |i|
  row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
  contact = Contact.find_by_id(row["id"]) || Contact.new
  contact.attributes = row.to_hash.slice('first_name', 'last_name', 'mobile', 'email', 'info')
  contact.user_id = self.user_id # this should work!
  contact
end
```

end

As you didn't mention where the Contact#load_imported_contacts either called in any before_save or before validation callback or not. But the way I mentioned the the `current_user.id` should be initialized to that contact model while persisting the data to `user_id` field. 
I hope this should be enough to solve your problem.

Thanks!

Comment: The user_id field is still showing up empty. I even tried adding it again from the model method. There are no callbacks. I have updated the question with the complete model and controller code for better clarity.

Comment: Thanks, please add sufficient information. So I can try more accurate solution.

Comment: I have pasted the full model and controller code in the original question above. Thanks for taking the time to help me out. Looking forward to the solution.

Comment: I just updated the answer. Just see this line:
    `@contact_import.user_id = current_user.id`